# Strange outline around skewed pseudo element in button

Tags: css

I'm using a pseudo element in a button to achieve an angled border. But in some browsers and some zoom levels, if you look closely you'll see a faint outline around the pseudo element towards the right of the button on the left edge of the pseudo element.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jw1kfmsh/

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 53px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-right-width: 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all .425s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1;
  filter: blur(0);
}

.button::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: -19px;
  top: -4px;
  height: 53px;
  width: 38px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 0;
  transform: skew(-31deg);
  transition: all .425s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Button Text</a>
```

Comment: .button:focus {outline: none;}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider a different idea where you will not have the issue. Make the shape as only one element and rely on overflow to hide the non needed part.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 40px 0 20px;
  line-height: 53px;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.button::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  left:-5px;
  bottom:0;
  background: red;
  border: 4px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(-31deg);
  transform-origin:top;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Button Text</a>
```